# Как загрузить изображение на сервер?

Tags: c#, uwp

Появилась необходимость загружать изображения на сервер. Т.е выбираю изображение FileOpenPicker и передаю его на некий сервер... На андроид достаточно много тем, а по с# что-то найти не могу(

Comment: Первая страница в поисковике - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326045/upload-photo-using-the-fileopenpicker-windows8-1

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin По моему это загрузка и вывод изображения в само приложение, а мне необходимо минуя приложение, сразу грузить на сервер...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.PostAsync(изображение в нужном виде);
```

Comment: А где указать адрес на который отправлять изображение? И как его принять на сервере?

Comment: Я показал в какую сторону копать. У `client` есть свойство BaseUri, можно указать адрес. Что значит, как принять на сервере? Следующий вопрос будет "Что такое хостинг?"?